# popen to pass binary data between processes

Tags: c, ipc, pipe, popen

I am facing issue in passing binary data between processes. My program opens a pipe to ffmpeg using popen() and tries to capture the output and then stream it as HTTP server.

I am doing something like this

```
ffmpeg -i "input_video.avi" -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 1500000 -r 25 -s 800x600 -f flv -
```

(Output filename "-" diverts the output to stdout)

After opening I am using fread() to read the pipe.

I can read it and my program streams content, when I downloaded the file on my browser, it completed, but the output file is not playable!!!

I am suspecting pipe opened to be "non-binary" handle as I opened it with popen("", "r"), as "r" in fopen is for text file opening.

But I am not able to open it with "rb" like I do for fopen(), as "rb" is not acceptable by popen().

How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

```
#define FFMPEG_COMMAND "ffmpeg -i %s -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 1500000 -r 25 -s 800x600 -f flv -"
```

*Code Opening pipe*

```
Opening_pipe(filename)
{
    STREAMING_HANDLE *vfp = NULL;
    char command[512] = {  0 };


    vfp = (STREAMING_HANDLE *)malloc(sizeof(STREAMING_HANDLE));
    if(NULL != vfp)
    {
        sprintf(command, FFMPEG_COMMAND, filename);
        vfp->ffmpeg_pipe = popen( command, 
                                  "r" );

        if( NULL == vfp->ffmpeg_pipe )
        {
            free(vfp);
            vfp = NULL;
        }
    }    
    printf("Virt_dir_fopen : vfp => 0x%X\n", vfp);
    return vfp;
}
```

*Code for reading from pipe*

```
Reading_data_from_pipe(fileHnd, buff, buflen)
{
    STREAMING_HANDLE *vfp = (STREAMING_HANDLE *)fileHnd;
    int ret_code;
    printf("Virt_dir_fread : Asking for %d bytes \n", buflen);
    ret_code =  fread(buf, 1, buflen, vfp->ffmpeg_pipe );
    printf("Virt_dir_fread : Returning %d bytes \n", ret_code);

    return ret_code;
}
```

*Code for closing pipe (For completeness :) )*

```
Closing_pipe(fileHnd)
{
    STREAMING_HANDLE *vfp = (STREAMING_HANDLE *)fileHnd;
    pclose(vfp->ffmpeg_pipe);
    free(vfp);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update-2:**

Compared the files

1) File-1 => Obtained by piping the data out off ffmpeg

2) File-2 => Obtained directly from ffmpeg using the same configuration

There are differences that I can see, 
1) File_Duration_field in File-1 is 0 but File-2 has some value. 
2) File_size_field in File-1 is 0 but File-2 has some value
3) File-1 has some extra 18 bytes at the end which is not present in File-2. Looks like the missing detailed about file_size and file_duration.

This looks natural isn't it? as ffmpeg doesn't know exact file_size of output it might have put it as 0 in the header of file-1 (But still wonder why it has to put 0 for duration in file-1).

My goal is to transcode my videos files into flv and stream them simultaneously so I don't have to wait for the conversion or have to convert everything in advance. But accomplishing this looks not possible this way. Is there any way for me to do this???

Any help/suggestion will be highly helpful and appreciated.

Regards,

Microkernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output may be raw data without a container. So, there is no way for an application to know how to interpret the binary data in the file.

You may also want to try using the [ffmpeg pipe option](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC41) to see if that has an effect on the output.

> Note that some formats (typically
>   MOV), require the output protocol to
>   be seekable, so they will fail with
>   the pipe output protocol.

Comment: Hi Judge, Hmm, but I use ffmpeg directly with that command asking it to write to a file, the output file will have no issues. But facing issue if I pipe it to my app and store it. So, shouldn't be issue with the container right?

Comment: You're probably right. I didn't look up those ffmpeg options. Have you tried diff'ing the output to a file versus what you get over HTTP?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't done it, will do it and see for the difference. Thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: Hi Judge, Please see the file comparison results under Update-2 in the post. Any suggestions on what I can do next?

Comment: Did you use the exact same method to get file 2? In other words, `ffmpeg -i %s -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 1500000 -r 25 -s 800x600 -f flv - > file2.flv`.

Comment: Hmm, I used didn't divert output to file using ">" but did something like ffmpeg -i %s -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 1500000 -r 25 -s 800x600 -f flv out.flv, and then compared this out.flv with the file I had obtained by my program. This is a godd idea, will do this, compare and comeback with results. Thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: Hi Judge, sorry I was out for long. I did ffmpeg *** > file_dump.flv. This file and the file-1 (One obtained by piping and streaming) match perfectly!!!

Comment: @Microkernel So, you issues must be related to the streaming format. That at least validates the rest of your system.

Comment: Hmm yeah, Any software like ffmpeg which can generate streamable flvs directly?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're using linux, or some other unix. In that case there's no distinction between opening something in binary mode or text mode. You don't need the "b" flag at all. Your problem lies elsewhere.

From the [fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) manpage:

> The mode string can also include the letter ''b'' either as a last character or as a character between the characters in any of the two-character strings described above. This is strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the ''b'' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux. (Other systems may treat text files and binary files differently, and adding the ''b'' may be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that your program may be ported to non-Unix environments.)

Comment: Hi Paul, Yes I am using Ubuntu. Would more code snippet be helpful? Updating question with some more code snippet.

Comment: Added more code snippets showing how I am opening and using pipe handles.

Comment: To debug this I might try to compare my file with the output of running ffmpeg from the command line. Print a hex dump as you read and compare that to a hexdump of the known good file. The code that ties together the reading of data from the pipe could be a source of errors.

Comment: Hi Paul, Please see the file comparison results under Update-2 in the post. Any suggestions on what I can do next?