# Named pipes and can they stream data?

Tags: ffmpeg, named-pipes

I asked a previous question here:

[Stream video from ffmpeg and capture with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574554/stream-video-from-ffmpeg-and-capture-with-opencv)

and I want to know more about named pipes in general.  Can I use named pipes to stream data?  For example, can I continuously add data to the pipe (via ffmpeg) in conjunction with reading data with another application?  Or is there another method to do this?

Answer (score -4):

you can check [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284982/using-pipes-to-channel-file-i-o-to-another-process) and have a look at [ffmpeg documentation on pipe section](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe)

Comment: Just posting links is frowned upon. Put the answer on the page of the question or don't post at all. That second link was particularly unhelpful. The word "pipe" appears on the page exactly once and doesn't do anything to answer the question.

Comment: ffmpeg document only explains UNIX pipe usage, not mentioned Windows named pipe.